# How to remove widget_css_bundle.css, authorization.css and pluseone.js on Blogger

Tags: xhtml, blogger

How can I remove it? I've tried to look it up in the template editor but still could not find it. It makes loading so long.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the following workaround as in practice you are not supposed to remove those files from loading. You need to change:

```
<b:skin><![CDATA[

......

CSS code...

......

]]></b:skin>
```

with this:

```
&lt;style type=&quot;text/css&quot;&gt;

&lt;!-- /*<b:skin><![CDATA[*/]]></b:skin>

<style type='text/css'> 
......

CSS code...

......
 </style>
```

Hope that works, here's the source for you:
http://i-blogger-you.blogspot.com/2014/03/hiding-css-reset-stylesheet-di-blogger.html